# Make viewing of edits link more obvious

Tags: feature-request, usability, edits

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387456/how-do-i-know-what-part-of-my-question-was-edited-by-another-user-in-stackoverflo) popped up recently in Stack Overflow, asking how to check what edits were made to the post.

User Nishant raised a good point in the comments. Clicking on the `99 mins ago` link is hardly intuitive for new users.

Might I suggest that that link be augmented with the text `(view revisions)` or something equally obvious?

Possibilities are to just add `(view revisions)` to the end of the link text or to take the time-ago out of the link altogether (leave it as text) and just place `View revisions` under the time.

Comment: +1. And while this is obviously not a solution your _new_ users, there is a nice [greasemonkey script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2047/add-hidden-links) to add `revisions` and `timeline` links

Comment: Something that could make it more intuitive would be to add a small icon next to the date of the modification, something like a magnifying glass.