# How do I know what part of my question was edited by another user in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, revisions-list, diff

I have asked a question in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and another user edited it. But how do I know what all changes he made in my question?

I couldn't figure out his changes.

Comment: For questions like these, click on "meta" on the top menu, or go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: there's a `x minutes ago` link that takes you to revisions page. But, I guess there should be an explicit link saying **`view revisions`** to see the revisions. `x moments ago` is not intuitive.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84181/make-viewing-of-edits-link-more-obvious

Answer (score 4):

You can see I have edited your question. You can see the changes by clicking on the `x moments ago` link next to `edited`

or

you can create the URL to revisions manually 
e.g. If your question URL is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387456` your revisions will be `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5387456/revisions`

basically, `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/[QUESTION_ID]/revisions`